# Regex Match Unknown Number of alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, linux, path

I am working on a project to delete files on a linux machine and I am thinking that using a regex pattern to select certain files and then delete them is the way to go. I'm am trying to match something on the lines of

```
abc_(alphanumeric)_(alphanumeric)_(two digit alphanumeric range)(arbitrary alphanumeric between 0 and 4 characters)_a.zip
```

or for example `abc_1_2_(12-50)****_a.zip` where the stars can be any number.
I'm pretty sure I can figure most of this regex out myself, but is there any way to match any number of random numbers before the `_a.zip`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for * or +. * is zero or more occurrences, + is one or more. You'll have to finagle it a bit if you have a different requirement than that.

I'm a bit rusty on regex, but I believe something along the lines of

```
abc_[0-9]_[0-9]_([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])[0-9]+_a\.zip
```

is what you're looking for.